# Hide/Show multiple DIV Class toggle | WP/Jquery

Tags: wordpress, class, toggle, hide

I've trawled the site and not found a solution, thus would appreciate guidance with the following:

I display a list of wordpress post excerpts on a page, each in it's own DIV. 
I output the post tags into the DIV class.

What I'm trying to achieve is a custom filter based on DIV class.
On initially opening the page all DIVs are displayed. 
Then onclick only DIVS of the desired class remain visible.
This is slightly more complicated as most DIVS will comprise multiple WP tags in their class.

An example of the html could be:

```
<a href="[command to show all DIVS]">All</a>
<a href="[command to show only class 'apple']">Apples</a>
<a href="[command to show only class 'mango']">Bananas</a>
<a href="[command to show only class 'orange']">Oranges</a>

<div class="apple orange">
<h3>Post 1 Title:</h3>
<p>Post excerpt</p>

<div class="apple">
<h3>Post 1 Title:</h3>
<p>Post excerpt</p>

<div class="mango orange">
<h3>Post 1 Title:</h3>
<p>Post excerpt</p>
```

etc

Can this be done with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved with jQuery.

Try doing something like this -

```
<a href="javascript:$('.tag').show();return false;">All</a><!-- Show all tag class -->
<a href="javascript:$('.tag').hide(); $('.apple').show();return false;">Apples</a><!-- Hide all tag class then show only apple class -->
<a href="javascript:$('.tag').hide(); $('.mango').show();return false;">Mango</a><!-- Hide all tag class then show only mango class -->
<a href="javascript:$('.tag').hide(); $('.orange').show();return false;">Oranges</a><!-- Hide all tag class then show only orange class -->

<div class="tag apple orange"><!-- Add tag class -->
    <h3>Post 1 Title:</h3>
    <p>Post excerpt</p>
</div>

<div class="tag apple"><!-- Add tag class -->
    <h3>Post 1 Title:</h3>
    <p>Post excerpt</p>
</div>

<div class="tag mango orange"><!-- Add tag class -->
    <h3>Post 1 Title:</h3>
    <p>Post excerpt</p>
</div>
```

Yes you will require jQuery to do this.

Comment: Thanks - that approach does seem to work.
However I seem to be missing something...
Onclick my DIVs are filtered as desired, but I'm then instantly diverted away to a blank page which says only: [object Object]
(With a bizarre url)

Comment: Please see updated code above. Add `return false;` to the href to avoid being taken to blank page.

Comment: I've added the code as suggested, but now the links don't do anything.

Comment: All sorted - thanks very much for helping lead me to a solution.
Here's what eventually worked - I'll include incase it helps anyone else:
I separated the code into external script:
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showapples").click(function(){
    $('.tag').hide(); $('.apples').show();
 return false;
  });
});
</script>`
Then call it in my a tag:
` <a href="#" id="showapples">Apples</a><br />`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you -

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="apple">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="mango">Mango</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="orange">Orange</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="grids">

    <div class="grid apple">apple</div>
    <div class="grid apple">apple</div>
    <div class="grid mango">mango</div>
    <div class="grid mango">mango</div>
    <div class="grid orange">orange</div>
    <div class="grid orange">orange</div>
    <div class="grid orange">orange</div>

</div>
```

and jquery

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('ul li a').click(function(){
        var data = $(this).attr('rel');
        if(data == 'all'){
            $('.grids .grid').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.grids .grid').hide();
            $('.grids .grid.'+data).show();
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

see live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/5kk3K/

Hope this will help you :)